# sorry you don't have permission to query for users

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, person-or-group

This is my scenarios:

1. I have a list with "Person or Group" column, i changed the
   SelectionGroup (from All Users to specified SharePoint Group name
   **Audi** which contain some persons 'let's name them ***P***'.

[image: Screenshot1]

2. I have 2 differents users (**User A and User B**) with the same permission level and same SharePoint Group (**SP Group: SiteOwners, Permission level: FullControl**)
3. When i try to write the first letter of ***P***, for the **User A** the autocomplete field works fine and the specified user will appear to him and select him, while for the **User B** it show me the following message: `sorry you don't have permission to query for users`

Note: If i change the Audi SP Group to another defaul site group (for example SiteMembers), it will work fine for both Users !

Comment: Isn't the Audi group configured to only let current members see who are the members? Are both users in the same scenario considering membership and ownership of the Audi group?

Comment: ah indeed !! you are right Pedro, I found that only members who can view the group members, while it should be Everyone, you should post your Answer and i will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have discussed in the comments, the Audi group is configured to only let current members see who are the members.

If the group is configured in that way then other users will receive permission errors while trying to select the values in the list.

Answer (score 2):

To correct this same issues we had to find the group within SharePoint and open it to see the members. On this screen you need to go to "Settings - Group Settings", then changed the option "Who can view the membership of the group?" from "Group Members" to "Everyone".
[image: Settings - Group Settings]
[image: Who can view the membership of the group? - Everyone]